# How should I configure pom.xml to keep A and B in my private local Maven repo cache while using Maven Central and java.net's Maven repositories?

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-central, javolution

How should I configure pom.xml to keep A and B in my private local Maven repo cache while using Maven Central and java.net's Maven repositories?

I've got two local private projects, call them A and B, but both depend on a few bug fixes in `org.javolution:javolution-core-java:6.1.0-SNAPSHOT`, which isn't in Maven Central.  Both A and B depend on other artifacts which are in Maven Central.  Project B depends on project A.

I'm used to using Maven with the local repository (cache) in ~/.m2 and Central, but it seems like I'm not configuring the project correctly for the java.net repository.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>B</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera.link.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>opera-link-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javolution</groupId>
            <artifactId>javolution-core-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.net Maven Repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>A</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javolution</groupId>
            <artifactId>javolution-core-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.net Maven Repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Removing the `<repositories>` element from B produces the obvious result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building B 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for org.javolution:javolution-core-java:jar:6.1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.547s
Finished at: Wed Jan 29 17:19:48 EST 2014
Final Memory: 3M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding the `<repositories>` element back in to B gives this on running:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building B 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ B ---
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package com.redacted.A.posts does not exist
    at com.redacted.B.App.<clinit>(App.java:30)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.219s
Finished at: Wed Jan 29 17:50:45 EST 2014
Final Memory: 4M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I'm typing this, I'm realizing perhaps this might not be a Maven problem as much as a NetBeans problem.  I clicked the "Re-Run Goals" button expecting a clean-and-build (as that's what I last executed), but doing a real clean-and-build seems to compile correctly, while "Re-Run Goals" just makes mvn run the exec goal.  Is my pom.xml configured correctly?

**Edit:** I'm using NetBeans 7.4.

Comment: you didn't mention what version of netbeans you are using nor what action you executed (Clean&build or Run?) in any case this document could help if this indeed is a netbeans issue - http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave#Using_Compile_on_Save_in_Maven_Projects

Answer (score 0):

Your first error message means that the javolution-SNAPSHOT couldn't be found. You have to provide a jar with pom in your local repository or buy using the java.net-repository.

The second error message results from running project B by the Exec-Maven-Plugin. The strange message seems a little bit missleading.

I would recommend you:

- First put your custom javolution-SNAPSHOT.jar into your local maven repository by using the maven install-goal
- If in doubt, which libraries you need from java.net, put the repository location into Project A as well as Project B.
- Next install Project A into your local maven repository by using the maven install-goal.
- Next install Project B into your local maven repository.